# Embed Google map URL inside android App

Tags: android, html, google-maps

I use a Map url link inside my website to automatically display a map Using HTML.
Is there a simple way in which i can include that inside my application as well?
thank you

Comment: You can reach any URL from inside any android app, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: In my website, i just paste the map link and there is an automatic display of the map . can i include this in an android app? where there will be a tiny map and if user clicks onto it, it takes the user to google maps for navigation...

Comment: You can, in Android, build an url, with the parameters your website requires to display the map, and present that url in a WebView in the layout of an Activity. But, there are more efficient ways to achieve what you want, like using the Google Maps API for Android, for example.